# How to check when user authorizated and user's ID :)

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        User.SetUser(Login1.UserName // and what is user ID ?
```

and how to check in other module if user authenticated or not ?

Comment: can you explain `User` belongs to which library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if the user is authenticated:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

To get his username if authenticated:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: thank you very mutch , but how to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363100/membership-how-to-set-userid-to-integer-s-and-not-encrypted ... can I use some integer value as ID ?