# Membership : How to set userID to integer :S and not encrypted

Tags: asp.net

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership](
 [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
```

Is there any easy ways to use and integer value as UserID (not this encrypted ...)

I really need integer :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily write a [custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) that uses your database rather than the default ASP.NET one.

This is the main reason Microsoft went down the provider model, they have supplied an interface that you need to implement, and then the other tools (UI, access controls, etc) can all work with it.

A sample implementation can be found on MSDN:

> [How to: Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx)

You'll notice that the [`ProviderUserKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx) on the [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) is an Object, not a GUID, so you can use an Int, String, or whatever does it for you.

Another option would be to store this link in the users Profile, and then do the relevant lookups from there, but that wouldn't be as clean.

**Edit to respond to comment**

Well, it depends on where you want to do the work really. If you are happy to replicate the ASP.NET Membership stored procedures in your SQL database, you could get away with creating a class that (like the sample) inherits from `MembershipProvider` and only provide an override of the `CreateUser` method to create an integer based key, rather than a GUID based one.

Basically, the sample is showing you a complete implementation of a membership provider - all of those methods are implemented in much the same way in MembershipProvider, the `override` keyword on the methods and properties is telling the framework "Use my methods instead of the base class methods please".

Comment: Yes , I will do it. I need your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Membership has GUID as UserId

```
MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
string UserID = myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString(); // it is the GUID as string
```

Of course, you can add other table  UserId GUID, UserIdAsInteger and link it one-to-one with membership one, but you need some additional coding.

Comment: MS has created this framework. :) Membership has UI, so it is a complete solutions :)

Of course, you can add other table <UserId GUID, UserIdAsInteger int> and link it one-to-one with membership one, but you need some additional coding: first you have to create User in Membership then add record to your table that has integer identifier (for example)

Comment: I need to use it from MS-SQL+WinApplication like currUser=AQ1UserId->Value.ToInt(); to config some things for some users

Comment: Guid.GetHashCode() - one way convertion ;)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know. What language do you use?

Comment: Guid to string, string to int

Comment: System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()
In the instance of the object reference not set to an object.

Comment: How to get Guid from DataBase ?? you mean UserId ? Then it's b5c26e9b-db3a-4865-abb0-e7f2746cb012 and It just can't be converted to int.

Comment: Можно icq или что-то подобное ? :/ Ато я с ума сойду от бeзисходности :)

Comment: i have no any access via any messenger at this moment. you should, I think, convert guid to string and string to int http://codenewbie.com/forum/platform-api-c/2139-guid-string-conversion.html and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/